# Employee Year Calculation

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have `employees` table with `date_of_join` field

and I have `employee_leaves` table with the following fields:

```
employee_id
leave_from
leave_to
total_days
```

the employee joined on 15 Feb 2011

I want to have a query showing the cound of leaves for every employee years based on his date_of_join

for example, if the employee joined on 15 Feb 2011 then the result will be like this:

```
Feb 2011 to feb 2012 ---- totals days: 21
Feb 2012 to feb 2013 ---- totals days: 26
Feb 2013 to feb 2014 ---- totals days: 8
```

where Feb to feb is the employee year so it's from 15 Feb to 14 Feb every year

can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Not having your data it is difficult to test this but I came up with the following based on your description:

```
SELECT  employees.employee_id, DATE_ADD(employees.date_of_join, INTERVAL yrs.years) frm 

,DATE_ADD(employees.date_of_join, INTERVAL yrs.years + 1) too,
    SUM(employee_leaves.total_days)
FROM employee_leaves
INNER JOIN (SELECT 0 years UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) yrs 
ON 1=1
INNER JOIN employees ON employee_leaves.employee_id = employees.employee_id
AND employee_leaves.leave_from BETWEEN DATE_ADD(employees.date_of_join, INTERVAL yrs.years) AND DATE_ADD(employees.date_of_join, INTERVAL yrs.years + 1) 
GROUP BY employees.employee_id, DATE_ADD(employees.date_of_join, INTERVAL yrs.years)
;
```

Probably needs some fiddling, hope this helps.

Comment: sorry! I am lost! why too many unions? and I am getting [Err] 1064 when running your code. Regarding the data, I don't have a data yet. All I have is empty employees and employee_leave tables with the same fields I mentioned in my question

Comment: I made a slight edit. The UNIONS are just to produce a list of year increments to join to (you`d need more to go further than 10 years). Really I intended this just to show you the direction to work in, it is not a tested piece of code.